# How to Remove Managed Package References in Profile and Permission Set Metadata

Tags: deployment, metadata

One of the most time-consuming components of migrating an org to a new server is dealing with managed package references in permission sets and profiles. There can be hundreds or thousands of references per XML file. What is the best way to find and remove these references other than spending days searching and manually deleting?

Answer (score 1):

First, I looked around for a tool that could automate this and then I started looking at search and replace functionality in dedicated XML editors. It looked like Oxygen could probably do the job but it was cost prohibitive for me. What I ended up doing was writing a regular expression and then using search and replace w/regex in Textmate (after trying a few other editors, including VSCode). The following are the regular expressions I used to eliminate all managed package references from permission sets and profiles:

```
<.+\s*<apexClass>mcdm_15\w*<.+\s*<.+\s*<\/classAccesses>
<.+\s*<.+\s*<field>mcdm_15\w*\.\w*<.+\s*<.+\s*<\/\w*>
<.+\s*<.+\s*<.+\s*<.+\s*<.+\s*<.+\s*<object>mcdm_15\w*<.+\s*<.+\s*<.+\s*<\/objectPermissions>
<.+\s*<tab>mcdm_15\w*s*<.+\s*<.+\s*<\/tabVisibilities>
<.+\s*<application>mcdm_15<.+\s+<.+\s+<.+\s+<\/applicationVisibilities>
<.+\s*<apexPage>tdc_tsw\w*<.+\s*<.+\s*<\/pageAccesses>
```

Textmate allows performing regular expression search and replace operations on entire directories, which meant that I could remove 20,000 managed package references from all profiles in less than a minute (either use version control or make a quick safety copy of the entire directory before each search and replace operation).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I built a [command](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdx-hardis#sfdx-hardisprojectcleanreferences--t-string--c-string--d---json---loglevel-tracedebuginfowarnerrorfataltracedebuginfowarnerrorfatal) that cleans permission sets & profiles from unwanted items references in a sfdx project (should work on metadata project too)

For the moment it works with:

- content of a destructiveChanges.xml file
- data.com fields (CleanStatus etc...)
- local fields (Contact.FirstNameLocal ...)
- custom cleaning config file (destructiveChanges-like.xml or config.json)

Install & interactive clean type select:

```
npm i sfdx-hardis sfdx-essentials -g
sfdx hardis:project:clean:references
```

with custom config (with content of your managed package for example):

```
sfdx hardis:project:clean:references --config ./somefolder/myDestructivePackage.xml
```

Feel free to provide feedbacks and contribute :)

Note: this command is also available in [VsCode SFDX Hardis extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis)

[image]